# Button encima de un editText

Tags: android, xml, botón

realmente no se si ese es el titulo mas adecuado pero necesito lograr que un button este
por encima de un editext , en la imagen continuacion se ve lo que necesito , por ahora este es el codigo que tengo en el xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/App"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.cjamcu.ligo.LoginActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.cjamcu.ligo.lib.AssetDrawableCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_email"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                    app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp" />

                <ImageButton

                    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.RoundedCornerMaterialButton"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Respecto a lo que comentas, me parece que tu duda ya se resolvió **aquí**: [Android EditText and Button on same line
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571923/android-edittext-and-button-on-same-line) Saludos.

Comment: Realmente se parece bastante pero no, yo necesito q no haya una separacion entre ambos componentes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
He aquí exactamente lo que necesitas.

*drawables/btn.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid  android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
            <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

*/drawables/edit.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke  android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
                <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
                <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="0dp"/>
           </shape>
        </item>
</selector>
```

*layout/edit_boton_ejempo.xml*

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/mail"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/edit"
    android:hint="rsanjuan1987@gmail.com"
    android:paddingEnd="50dp"
    android:paddingStart="50dp"
    android:singleLine="false" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn"
    android:src="@drawable/send"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton" />
```

*Acepta mi respuesta si te sirve y dale +1 si de agrada*

**Edit**
asignación de backgrounds estaba mal

Comment: podrias explicar un poco mas todos los recursos

Comment: ja por que el -1?

Comment: Bruno el recurso de btn.xml es el fondo para el boton, el edit.xml es el fondo para el edit y en layout el boton se sobre pone al edit haciendo q pareca que esta dentro

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag si eres mas especifico puedo aclarar mas

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de un `Linearlayout` utiliza un `RelativeLayout` esto para que puedas posicionar la imagen a la derecha del `EditText` mediante la propiedad [android:layout_alignRight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignRight)

Este es un ejemplo que tengo donde defino que el `ImageButton` se posicionará a la derecha del `EditText`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="username@puisor.com"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myEditText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

para obtener

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En tu código sería de esta forma reemplazando el contenedor del `EditText` y el `ImageButton` por un `RelativeLayout`:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.cjamcu.ligo.lib.AssetDrawableCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"                    
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            style="@style/AppTheme.RoundedCornerMaterialButton"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_email" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```